# Configuring Spring Boot with Spring-Cloud-Connectors to use the PWS Config-Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am having a hard time to configure my Spring Boot application to connect to the PWS (Pivotal Web Services) provided **Config-Server via Spring-Cloud-Connectors**.

In the manifest.yml the config server is bound to the application, which is correctly reflected by the corresponding, VCAP_SERVICES entry:

```
applications:
- name: edge-service-webapp-myapp
  services:
  - infrastructure-config-server
  memory: 512M
  env:
    TRUST_CERTS: api.run.pivotal.io
    SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT: cloud
  instances: 1
  host: edge-service-webapp-myapp
  domain: cfapps.io
  buildpack: java_buildpack

{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "p-config-server": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "access_token_uri": "https://p-spring-cloud-services.uaa.run.pivotal.io/oauth/token",
     "client_id": "p-config-server-84d66ea6-ebc6-xxx",
     "client_secret": "***",
     "uri": "https://config-b4320676-xxx.cfapps.io"
    }, ...
}
```

The application is build with spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.2.RELEASE, spring-cloud-dependencies Camden.SR5 and spring-cloud-services-dependencies 1.4.1.RELEASE. Also I am using spring-cloud-starter-config and spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors as explicit dependencies.

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
             ....
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       ...
```

When I curl the config server I can see the application version available for the application-name (my-app) and the active 'cloud' profile.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true


curl -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" https://config-b4320676-xxx.cfapps.io/tradefoundry/cloud
{"name":"my-app","profiles":["cloud"],"label":"master","version":"389e4f909ff1303332167b2159b4d75201109d69","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://gitlab.com/myapp/configuration.git/myapp-cloud.properties","source":{"spring.thymeleaf.cache":"true","message":"Hello Cloud!"}},{"name":"https://gitlab.com/myapp/configuration.git/myapp.properties","source":{"server.compression.enabled":"true","spring.thymeleaf.cache":"true","application.version":"0.0.1"}},{"name":"https://gitlab.com/myapp/configuration.git/application.properties","source":{"server.compression.enabled":"true","spring.thymeleaf.cache":"true","application.cache.busting.enabled":"false","application.version":"0.0.1-20170202195700","server.compression.mime-types":"application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript"}}]}
```

**But still the application fails at startup, complaining about the missing property application.version.**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myWebappApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.version' in value "${application.version}"
```

What am I missing here? I thought the cloud connectors were all plug-and-play through autoconfiguration!?

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the Spring Cloud Services config server provided on PWS, you need to use a different set of client libraries as shown in the [PWS docs](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/client-dependencies.html).

Replace the dependencies on `spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors` and `spring-cloud-starter-config` with just this one dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The Spring Cloud Services config server adds additional OAuth2-based security on top of the open-source Spring Cloud Config server. This client-side library does the OAuth negotiation automatically.

Comment: You saved my day! ... and now I feel a bit stupid for skipping that part of the documentation ... sloppy me ...

Comment: Docs are great - once you find out that they exist and where they live. These may not be the easiest docs to find. I'm glad to hear that fixed your problem.